# qt qmake -set environment variables

Tags: linux, qt, makefile, qmake

As per documentation here 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html

I am trying to set **QMAKE_CXXFLAGS** and **QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG** variables.

Basically I want to dynamically add some compiler flags to generated make file. e.g. -**ggdb** OR **-j** depending upon requirement. I do not want to make it permanently in **.pro** files.

I am setting using ***-set***. when I again use ***-query***, i am unable to see that variable.

Please let me know if i am missing something.

I want to dynamically generate debug builds and release builds or use **-j** flags. Which should be applicable to all the **qmake** commands i issue after setting environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe **QMAKE_CXXFLAGS** and **QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG** are settable using the `qmake -set`.  That command is only for "persistent properties."  `qmake -query` should give you a list of ones you can change.

That said, you can manually set the values when you invoke qmake by using the same line(s) you would in a .pro file.

```
qmake "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-j" "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG+=-ggdb" mystuff.pro
```